# Most Gambits Declined in a Single Game

Tags: gambits, queens-gambit-declined

Bit of an odd question that has arisen from a game that I played today. In the game it started of with the Queens Gambit (which appear to be the flavour of the month due to Netflix). I usually dont enjoy playing into it and ended up playing the Albin Counter Gambit (e5). In the first time in approximately 60 odd games of it, my counter gambit was declined.

```
[Event "How many Gambits?"]
[White "Random Hero"]
[Black "Yours Truly"]
[Result "*"]
[PlyCount "5"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 {Queens Gambit, accepting is taking the c4 pawn} e5 {Queens Gambit: Declined Albin Counter Gambit} 3. Nc3 {Albin Counter Gambit Declined. Accepted Line is usually dxe5} Bb4
```

This got me thinking. **How many gambits can exist in a single game?** I know in this instance 2 but I can't think of any other examples that have a 3rd Counter Gambit. Be curious if anyone knows of any other examples.

Most recent Master Game I can find with this position *Azmaiparashvili vs Kanep (2006)* which probably indicates its not the most sound theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a sequence of four gambits. Starting with Bird's Opening: **1. f4**:

- **1... e5** offers the From's Gambit
- **2. e4** offers the King's Gambit
- **2... d5** offers the Falkbeer Counter-gambit
- **3. d4** offers the Hinrichsen Gambit

And Black declines the last gambit with **3... Nf6**.

```
[FEN ""]

1. f4 e5 2. e4 d5 3. d4 Nf6
```

Comment: Now all we need is a name for 3 ... f5 rather than Nf6.